# How to remove emacs frametitle and surrounding space

Tags: frame-title-format

(setq frame-title-format "")  removes the emacs frame title but leaves a blank space.
How can I remove this blank space? I want to remove this blank space so that I have more screen space for viewing the buffer on a small laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have emacs built with an option to eliminate the titlebar entirely. If you use [emacs-plus](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus) this is easy. Build with the [--no-titlebar option](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus#no-titlebar). One complication is that you'll then need to use a tiling window manager to manage emacs frames.